# How to route associated VLAN subnet to my Vyatta on SoftLayer?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

This question is in reference to the following instructions:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/virtual-router-appliance?topic=virtual-router-appliance-managing-your-vlans#route-multiple-vlans-over-same-network-interface

I have configured the VLANs (public and private) that my Vyatta is associated with as "route through" from the gateway appliance settings on the SoftLayer portal.

After ssh-ing into the Vyatta, I try to configure it to effecitvely route the VLANs using the above instructions:

```
vyatta@vyatta-dal13# set interfaces bonding dp0bond1 vif 2586 address 52.116.44.192/28

  Configuration path: interfaces bonding dp0bond1 vif 2586 address [52.116.44.192/28] is not valid

  Must have one of the following values: dhcp, dhcpv6, <x.x.x.x/x>, <h:h:h:h:h:h:h:h/x>
  Value validation failed

  Set failed

[edit]
```

However, I get the error you see above. I don't understand why it is failing to validate that CIDR. It looks valid to me. Appreciate any hints here to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command configures an IP address of dp0bond1. So, 52.116.44.193/28 is used because 52.116.44.192/28 is a network address. Please try with 52.116.44.193/28

Comment: Thanks much! I should have caught this!